# Firebase Firestore onSnapchot not always giving me data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a form where users enter their location, if the user does not already have a location in the DB, he can upload one or more. If he already has a location, he can add more, or delete the ones he wants.

The problem is: even if I have a location stored, the onSnapshot request does not fetch the addresses every time. Sometimes when I reload the page, the locations are there but sometimes not. Also, when I upload an address using the form, sometimes it displays it below because the data is fetched, but sometimes not...

Here is a location in Firestore (using google geocoding data):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svvxd.png

Here is the useEffect to fetch the addresses from Firestore:

```
// fetch adresses from firestore 
useEffect(() => {
if (user) {
  console.log("1. FETCHING ADRESSES START");

  var userDocument = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("adresses")
    .where("clientId", "==", user.docId);


  userDocument.onSnapshot((adresses) => {
    const adressesArr = [];
     adresses.forEach((adresse) => {
      console.log(adresse.data());
      adressesArr.push(adresse.data()); 
    });
    console.log("adressesArr: ", adressesArr);
    setFetchedAdresses(adressesArr);
  });
  console.log("2. FETCHING ADRESSES DONE");
} else {
  console.log("user is not logged in ADRESSES");
}
return function cleanup() {
  console.log("DASHBOARD UNMOUNTED");
  setFetchedAdresses([]);
};}, []);
```

And here are screenshots of the app where you can see that sometimes addresses are fetched and sometimes not...
[adresses not fetched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08rKQ.png)
[addresses fetched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WHZt.png)

I really need Firestore's onSnapshot to see in real-time the changes made on each user address list.

If someone could help me, thank you!

Comment: What is your console logging? My guess is that this is more due to `user` than your snapshot listener. You're relying on `user` in your `useEffect` but it's not in the dependency array, so if `user` doesn't exist when the component is mounted, you get no addresses. Then if `user` changes, your code doesn't react to that to get the addresses.

Comment: Thank you a lot! You're right, It solved my problems :)